# AsyncTask newbie issue

Tags: java, android, class, android-asynctask

I cant figure out why the variable "vysledek" stays unchanged after calling the void "Send" from activity. I probably doesnt fully understand the way AsyncTask works. Thanks for help.

```
public class Tools{

   public String vysledek;

 public void Send() {
       Poslat Poslat = new Poslat();
       Poslat.execute();
}

private class Poslat extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            vysledek = "something I want it to be";
     }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    vysledek = "something I want it to be 2";
}
```

}

I want that the Activity that called "Send" have the variable already. So i guess it has to wait for it to finish. I tried to do the waiting like this:

```
 while (Tools.vysledek.equals(""))
            { }
```

But that causes crash.

Comment: where are you trying to access vysledek?

Comment: In the Activity that called the "Send()".

Comment: it causes a crash because vysledek is null until your AsyncTask finishes. look at @cadocx answer for the correct way to do it

Comment: I changed it like that but I need the Activity to wait and I dont know how..

Comment: It is better practice to call the equals as while ("".equals(Tools.vysledek)) to avoid null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Solved with `String vysledek = asyncTask.execute().get();`Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timing.  The asnc task happens on another thread.  But when the OS switches to that thread is up to the OS.  It should happen quickly (next few hundred ms), but it won't necessarily be immediate, so if you immediately check for it you may or may not see it changed.  The correct place to put code that requires the async task to have run is in onPostExecute.

Comment: But is there any way to make Activity wait for it to finish?

Comment: that defeats the purpose of doing it Async. put all the code that requires it in onPostExecute()

Comment: I want to deafeat it. Im doing it just so I can acces the HttpClient ;)

Comment: Do it onPostExecute anyway.  If you don't, your entire UI will freeze and be unresponsive, it looks like your app is broken.  Users won't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign it after the asynctask finishes

```
public class Tools{

   public String vysledek;

 public void Send() {
       Poslat Poslat = new Poslat();
       Poslat.execute(vysledek);
}

private class Poslat extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result){
     vysledek = "I should be here";
     }
}
```